# How do I insert a value in a radio button based choice column in a SharePoint 2013 list using REST API in JavaScript?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery, sharepoint-rest-api, ajax

Here are the columns I have in the backend list.[image]
Here's how I am sending the data to the backend list through a POST request using AJAX.

```
var item = {
    __metadata: { type: "SP.Data.ListNameListItem" },
    Column1: { '__metadata': {' type': 'Collection(Edm.String)' }, 'results':  ['data1'] },
    Column2: { '__metadata': {' type': 'Collection(Edm.String)' }, 'results':  ['data2'] }
}
```

For Column1, how do I select 1st radio button and select a value inside it and for Column2, how do I select 2nd radio button and send a text of my own into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example code for your reference.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function createListItem() {
    var listTitle="CL1224";
    var item = {
        "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data."+listTitle+"ListItem" },
        "Title":"MyTest",
        "Column1":"data1",
        "Column2":"data5"
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+listTitle+"')/items",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Success');
            //window.location.href=window.location.href;
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    });
}
</script>
<button type="button" onclick="createListItem()">Submit</button>
```

[image]

Comment: Oops, I didn't try the default method of sending just the data. This is working, thank you!